# Get JSONArray and write to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, java-8

I have the following object:

```
{
  "some_prop": "sweetvalue",
  "some_list": ["0f9f822cd7e64000ac056ebc17b82f1d", "0f9f82223094fj7b82f1d"]
}
```

And I'm trying to get `some_list` and write to `some_list`, afterwards saving to a file. using the following code:

```
public String getData(String key) { // this is confusion should be getConfigValue
    String data = getConfig();
    JSONObject jsonData;
    Object content = null;
    try {
        jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        if (key != null) {
            content = jsonData.getString(key);
        } else {
            content = jsonData.toString();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}

private void saveFile(String data) {
    File file = configFile;
    try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
        byte[] contentInBytes = data.getBytes();
        fop.write(contentInBytes);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void appendToArrayValue(String uuid) {
    JSONObject configData = new JSONObject(getConfig());
    JSONArray mutedPlayers = configData.getJSONArray("some_list");
    JSONArray uuidArray = new JSONArray(uuid);

    JSONArray newArray = concatArray(mutedPlayers, uuidArray);

    JSONObject newConfigData = configData.put("some_list", newArray);
    saveFile(newConfigData.toString());
}
```

When trying to run this code, I get the following error:

`org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

I'm not sure what's really wrong, I know my code is *terrible* but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is at line `JSONArray uuidArray = new JSONArray(uuid);`?

Because prevoius line `JSONArray mutedPlayers = configData.getJSONArray("some_list");` should work fine.
If so, you are passing not an array to `new JSONArray(uuid)` since uuid is your whole JSON object.